# How can I dismiss a modal segue from interface builder in Xcode 10 and Swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, xcode10

I've added a button in my ViewController. This view controller was activated with a modal segue.
How can i dismiss this from interface builder. I must to use an IBAction or can do it from interface builder?

Comment: Use an unwind segue

Comment: Would you please explain your question a little more

Comment: @AbhinavJha of course. I'have a table view controller with a list of element, this is wrapped by a navigation controller. In this view i have a "+" button in navigation bar for create a new item. I want to open the new item view in modal segue. That's ok. Now in the new view i'have in the navigation bar a cancel button and a save button. I'can't dismiss the segue and close this view.

Comment: @Kobazzo, please find my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.leftNavigationItemAction(_:)))
}

@objc func leftNavigationItemAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3:**

```
present(UIViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 2.2:**

```
self.presentViewController(true, completion: nil)
```

**Hide/dismiss a view controller:**

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

hope this will help , Thank you.

Comment: Thank You Fansad. Perfect solution.